# iOS-like Scrollview in as3 AIR

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I'm trying to create a iOS-like `UIScrollView` in ActionScript 3 for my Adobe AIR apps, but it is not very smoooth.

Why didn't Adobe implement a native scroll view? Has anyone already implemented a smooth scroll, using movie clips or something similar?

Comment: create your own scrolling list and item renderer using basic blitting techniques or even the Starling framework.  it's perfectly smooth and not difficult to create if you know how to program (Flash IDE timeline isn't programming), understand how basic list renderers function and know the performance difference between animating vector graphics and bitmaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this. It should give you some ideas/help you get started.

http://www.infin8iphone.co.uk/?p=57

Comment: awesome! Thank you guys, stackoverflow is the best coding-site ever!
Thank you crooksy88, it will help me so muchhh!!

Answer (score 1):

I had created a pretty full functional iOS-like ScrollView/ListView component for AS3, you can try it:
https://github.com/albert-zhang/AZASScroll