# as3 component like iOS' UIScrollView

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, uiscrollview

I'm searching for an as3 class that works similarly to the UIScrollView on iOS; ie. you can drag anywhere on the view (movie clip) and it will scroll the content inside.  I found the [ScrollPane](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/containers/ScrollPane.html) class, but it just has a bar along the right where you have to drag the bar or press the up and down arrows.  I want an intuitive class where you can swipe anywhere to scroll the view.  Is there anything like that out there?  I'm surprised I can't find something by searching.

For the record, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172033/ios-like-scrollview-in-as3-air), but its accepted answer links to a botched UITableView implementation, not UIScrollView.

Comment: You're right in that there aren't really any good ones out there.  I wrote my own in the end, but it's much too large to post here as an answer.  Perhaps when I have time I'll package it up and offer it to the community

Answer (score 0):

This is what you exactly want: https://github.com/albert-zhang/AZScroll

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, its not commented but its fairly straightforward.
All the .fla (not included) has is an MC called scroll_container that contained all the items.

```
    private var hasScrolled:Boolean = false;
    private var checkForScroll:Boolean = false;
    private var oldMouse:Point;

    public function IOSScrollTest() {

        addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseDown );
        addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp );
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, EnterFrame );
    }

    private function MouseDown( e:MouseEvent ) {

        hasScrolled = false;
        checkForScroll = true;
        oldMouse = new Point( mouseX, mouseY );
    }

    private function MouseUp( e:MouseEvent ) {

        if( ! hasScrolled ) {

            // Do your stuff here (onClick things)
        }

        checkForScroll = false;
    }

    private function EnterFrame( e:Event ) {

        if( checkForScroll ) {

            var diff:Number = mouseY - oldMouse.y;
            if( Math.abs(diff) > 2 ) {

                hasScrolled = true;
                oldMouse = new Point( mouseX, mouseY );
                scroll_container.y += diff;
            }
        }
    }
```